# Can moscovium-299 exist and is it possible to predict how stable it will be?

Tags: nuclear-physics, strong-force, elements, isotopes

Five isotopes of element 115 (moscovium) have been created in the laboratory with atomic weights ranging from 286 to 290, each having a progressively longer half-life, ranging from 20ms to 650ms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_moscovium

The famous UFO whistleblower Bob Lazar has allegedly claimed that moscovium-299 is stable and plays an important role in powering the retrieved spaceships of unknown origin, which he studied. Allegedly the large size of the element's nucleus creates a situation, where the strong force "permeates past the nucleus and can be accessed and amplified".

Are there calculations, which can be done to predict whether moscovium-299 is stable?

Is it possible to create moscovium-299 in a laboratory and how would we go about doing so? What would be the approximate cost of such a project and is anyone working on it?

What sort of natural processes in the known universe could create moscovium-299 and would it be possible to detect its presence over interstellar distances?

Comment: see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prvXCuEA1lw)

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, Moscovium-299 doesn't exist. The highest neutron number achieved is Moscovium-291.

Answer to question 1: no calculation for Moscovium-299 exist because Moscovium-299 doesn't exist.

Answer to question 2: we could try to create it by doing target-projectile collisions hoping miracously to turn known elements into Moscovium isotopes via hot fusion, but it's not gonna work with high probability for Moscovium-299.

Answer to question 3: no one is working on it because it's an irrilevant isotope, so no cost for this project were ever estimated by anyone.

Answer to question 4: no natural process will create it, it simply doesn't exist an will realistically never do. So no, you can't detect it since it doesn't exist. Also isotopes are measured by mass spectroscopy, which doesn't work at a distance. We measure only light and particles fluxes so if you know that Moscovium-299 has some special spectroscopical lines associated to nuclear transtions you could try to search for them.

Comment: I know that moscovium-299 doesn't exist, but can it exist? Is there anything fundamental in physics, which stops it from being made? Like, if you had a billionaire obsessed with creating it, could it be created?

Comment: I don't know, experiments have always the last word so if nobody try, we have no way of saying if it can be created. What we can infer by our theoretical knowledge is that if it can be created will decay very very quickly since the proton to neutron ratio is very high, almost 1:2, and it does not posses one of the magic numbers

Comment: There is no fundamental rule about not-existence of Moscovium-299, but you have to come up with a process which does not violate any rule and that can generate it. AFAIK now there isn't any known such process to do so

Answer (score 0):

Isotope-299 is a standard nuclear physics prediction. You can read it straight from a standard text book graph:

- [Brown et. al](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/21%3A_Nuclear_Chemistry/21.02%3A_Patterns_of_Nuclear_Stability)

Draw a circle around the island, & simply read off the number of neutrons (184), then add it to 115 = 299

However, I stress, it's just theoretical. Who knows ?